# Code after await doesn't work

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have the next code:

```
  static void Main()
    {
        Program.DownloadFile();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task DownloadFile()
    {
        using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            string address = "http://www.phantastike.com/link/astrology/predictive_astrology_a.zip";
            await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(address, "f.zip");
            // Here method returns
        }
        Console.WriteLine("This line not reached");
    }
```

When I start it  the program never reached to Console.WriteLine method. It returned after await.
But in the next code it works well:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program.DownloadFile();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task DownloadFile()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Task.Delay(2000));
        Console.WriteLine("Now you can see this message on console");
    }
```

Who can explain that? Thank you and sorry for my English

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't download? Can't reproduce your problem. Do you know where it actually saves the zip?

Comment: try covering it in try catch there you can see if the file is downloaded

Comment: Instead of Task.Delay(), throw an exception to repro your problem.  You don't wait for the async method to complete so you can't see it fail.

Answer (score 4):

This is what probably happens: You don't wait for `DownloadFile` to complete, the control returns to `Main`, you reach `Console.ReadKey`, you press on a key and the program ends before it had a chance to complete the download.

When you use `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Task.Delay(2000));` instead you're not really waiting the whole 2 seconds because `Task.Factory.StartNew` returns a `Task<Task>` so `Console.WriteLine` is reached immediately. You need to use `Task.Run` instead.

The problem is that you're not waiting for you operation to complete. Regularly you would do that with await, but that can't be used in `Main` so just in this case use `Task.Wait`:

```
static void Main()
{
    DownloadFile().Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with `await` usage here. You should monitor the download progress of the file you're downloading. Add event handler for `DownloadProgressChanged`

```
 using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
   {
     wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
     string address = "http://www.ayobamiadewole.com/Blog/Files/AOP.zip";
     await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(address, "f.zip");
   }

 static void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
   { 
       Console.WriteLine("\r{0} % Completed.", e.ProgressPercentage);
   }
```